# how to save the model result in a list in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, model, nested-lists

I ran an NLP model which the result has 8 sub-results. So basically, model m has some sub_model features and I can access them like m$phi. As shown below:

[image: model result]

what I am trying to do is saving these results in a list and use them later. This is how I approached it:

```
model <- c()
for (i in c(3:10)){
  m <- FitLdaModel(dtm,k = i,
                        iterations = 200,
                        burnin = 175)
  model <- append(model,m)
  i <- i+1
  
}
```

This approach is somehow working, but instead of **8 Values** saved in an empty list, I will get 72 values. Basically, all models and sub-models are saved in the list, but what I wanted was something like a **nested list** which has sub_models of model one in the first element, sub-models of model two in the second element, ... So I want to have a list like this:

final_list <- [[model m1 and all sub_model], [model m2 and all sub_model],...]

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try initialising a list first.

```
inds <- 3:10
model <- vector('list', length(inds))
for (i in seq_along(inds)) {
  model[[i]] <- FitLdaModel(dtm,k = inds[i],
                   iterations = 200,
                   burnin = 175)
}
```

Using `lapply` might be simpler I think :

```
model <- lapply(inds, function(i) FitLdaModel(dtm,k = i,iterations = 200, burnin = 175))
```